# jQuery Wait for Attr Change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have setup search functionality for my site using JQuery. All non-matching results are removed via toggle(), and there's a lot of data on the page. As you can image, the search takes several seconds to run.

To provide some user feedback that the search is running, I'm trying to replace the img source with a spinner gif.

Here's what I'm trying to do. On click() of the search button (or enter from the search box):

```
$('div#search img').attr('src', '/static/img/spinner.gif');
search_contacts(s);
$('div#search img').attr('src', '/static/img/search.gif');
```

I have the Chrome developer tools open and showing the network tab. As soon as I attempt a search, I see the GET request for spinner.gif registered. The problem is that this request is set to "pending," and never progresses while `search_contacts()` is running. The moment the search completes, the Gif loads (well, 304 not modified in 5ms).

What's the proper way to make jquery/javascript wait for the attribute change to complete before running the function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find your answer with jquery when().

Doc: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

```
$.when( search_contacts(s) ).done(function() {

      $('div#search img').attr('src', '/static/img/search.gif');
});
```

Comment: You didn't find your answer with this link ?

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work. The GET for the new gif always remains "pending" until the `search_contacts` function completes. (In your code, the attr change and function should be swapped. However, that doesn't have the correct behavior either.)